# Узнать текущую раскладку клавиатуры на си

Tags: c, клавиатура

Необходимо узнать какой язык установлен в текущем окне (раскладка клавиатуры), приложение должно работать на ос Windows и в консольном режиме. Пробовал следующие вариации кода, но они выдают всегда один язык, как сделать так что бы отлавливать текущее изменение языка?

```
   int getInputMethod() {
      HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
      if (hwnd) {
        DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL);
        HKL currentLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(threadID);
        unsigned int x = (unsigned int)currentLayout & 0x0000FFFF;
        return ((int)x);
     }
   }
```

Или так еще пробовал:

```
#ifdef WINVER
#undef WINVER
#endif
#define WINVER 0x500

GUITHREADINFO Gti;
::ZeroMemory ( &Gti,sizeof(GUITHREADINFO));
Gti.cbSize = sizeof( GUITHREADINFO );
::GetGUIThreadInfo(0,&Gti);
DWORD dwThread = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(Gti.hwndActive,0);
HKL lang = ::GetKeyboardLayout(dwThread);
```

Comment: Т.е. вы попросту хотите написать перехватчик клавиатуры, который бы записывал все логины и пароли, вводимые на компьютере? Я вас правильно понял? :)

Comment: Нет, хочу отлавливать определенные комбинации клавиш, символов. OUTPUT использую как лог файл, пытаюсь разобраться как избежать остановки потока stdin

Answer (score 0):

Для регистрации глобального обработчика клавиатурного сочетания существует функция [RegisterHotKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey). После регистрации нового сочетания при его возникновении в оконную процедуру указанного окна или в очередь сообщений потока будет отправляться сообщение `WM_HOTKEY`.

Comment: Где-то на SO был пример для чистого си, RegisterHotKey - это виндовая функция.

Comment: @nick_n_a Для чистого си примера быть не могло, так как в нем функции работы с клавиатурным / мышиным вводом отсутствуют в принципе, не говоря уж об обработке горячих клавиш.